# Does Amazon RDS have default setting on their postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-migration

## Background

I have a laravel application that uses migration/seeding scripts that have always worked fine when ran on my localhost (OSX) and even on an AWS ec2 instance when the db is local.

## Problem

The music started when I decided to connect the ec2 instance into a separate RDS instance (we're talking staging here), I ran my migration scripts as always, but then I got this rude error:

> SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  constraint
>   "users_type_check" of relation "users" does not exist (SQL: ALTER
>   TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_type_check;)

not sure why this is only happening on RDS, ideas?

Comment: RDS has default parameter group, but I dont see how it would be related to your error. In fact I don't see anything RDS specific in NOT NULL arror due to existing data - try to spin up new postgres instance and run your migration against it - I'd say you will get same error

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Vao's comment.

There is hardly anything RDS specific in that error message.

It seems you are under the impression that the *user_type_check* constraint is there, when in reality it may not.

You mentioned you are populating the database by running migrations, hence are you sure these have been ran and have populated the database correctly in the first place?